# Determining the name of a dropdownlist control that caused a post back onchange event in MVC

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

I have two html helper dropdownlists for displaying districts and towns in my mvc web application. I am using vb.net
below is two of my drop down lists in the view layer.

```
    @*Dropdownlist1*@

    @Html.DropDownList("Districts", Nothing, "All",
        htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "form-control", .onchange = "$(this).closest('form').submit();"})

    @*Dropdownlist2*@

    @Html.DropDownList("Towns", Nothing, "All",
            htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "form-control", .onchange = "$(this).closest('form').submit();"})
```

In my server side code, i need to know which of the two dropdownlists controls caused the post back after selection /change. 
i need a way of passing the dropdownlist name, or an equivalent as part of the values that are submitted.

Comment: You could instead compare the value of both dropdown with their previous value. The dropdown that has it's value change would be the one that executed the submit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used a viewbag dynamic property to set a value in my server side code, 
and I was hoping to send this value into the view layer, on perhaps a hidden control (which is named appropriatedly). 
The subsequent post back should include the value of the hidden control as part of the request. The hidden control
is not able to send this value through during the post back, though. How should i have
gone about it anyway?

Comment: When you do a view source, is the hidden control value properly set? When to postback is done, if you just do a Request.Form can you get the data? This might help you figure out where the problem is.